# In XCode 6, why are my modal segues sometimes slow to perform?

Tags: xcode, segue, uistoryboard

I am creating a Storyboard in XCode 6, and wiring up my views, and for some reason a modal segue from a tableview in one is really slow to perform.

Sometimes it works instantly, sometimes it takes a few seconds, and other times it doesn't work until I tap the screen (I thought this was really weird and could be a good indicator of what's happening!)

Getting no errors, any idea?

Thanks

Comment: You're probably doing some long-running work, possibly downloading something, on the main thread in the new view controller. You can use the Time Profiler instrument to see what's causing the delay. Or post the relevant code here and we can take a look. As it stands, it's impossible to answer your question for sure.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, but I'm literally just working on a Storyboard. The only thing I'm doing it running a query in the background on Parse.com to populate the tableview. Other than that, nothing. Will look at the Time Profiler though, thank you.

Comment: Also, when changing it to a Show Segue, the issue is gone.

Comment: I'm getting the same thing, though on Xcode 7 and *with* the Show segue. There's no logic going on, just Storyboard. Seems to work better on Simulator than on the device, where the tap takes a few seconds to segue. Weird :/

Answer (score 0):

Had this exact problem that took up most of my day.

Thought it was a coreData issue, re-did my whole stack, took out things I thought were causing the issue.

Turns out it was the modal segue set in the storyboard from the cell to the destination NavController.  Deleted the segue, then created a new segue NOT from the tableView cell but from the ViewController itself that has the tableView, then set the segueId to the same ID as before.  Then in ViewController added the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method to manually call the segue.

Solved the issue.  Hope this helps, have no idea why the segue from the cell was causing the issue.